# CSS menu dropdown is not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I know there's a lot of question about this but I've still not understood how make a css menu dropdown that works also in IE8.

I've made [this sample menu.](http://elena87.netsons.org/menu)

It works well in all browsers, except in IE8 in which you see [this.](http://www.elena87.netsons.org/menu/menu_ie8.jpg)

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me what does not work and how to fix. Thanks

Comment: Could you please a a jsfiddle

Comment: Sure! Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/Ak7ju/

Comment: in your jsFiddle file there is wrong html structure, please check

Comment: Instead of having `margin-top: 10px;` on the sub-menu, try giving it `top: 100%;` as it's positioned absolutely. That's a technique I've used many times in the past, and it works fine in IE8. Updated your demo with fixed HTML and my suggested fix: http://jsfiddle.net/rUQWy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mistake in your syntax if you see

**this is ur code**

```
          <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Item 1
                <ul>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 1</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 2</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 3</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 4</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 5</li></a>
                    </ul>

                </li>
               </a>
           </ul>
```

**what it should be is**

```
            <ul>
               <li>
                           <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                               <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
           </ul>
```

your syntax should be ul > li > a

What you can do is try changing the syntax of the code.

Comment: `<ul> <a href="#"><li>Sub-item 1</li></a>` isn't ul > li > a

Comment: I understand that looks like a css selector but i was trying to explain the codeflow, as how it should come.

Comment: Thanks! I finally found out what was wrong! I do not remember, maybe I set the css before entering the submenu, and I did it in the wrong way.

Comment: I know, and I meant your codeflow isn't ul > li > a, except for the first ul.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick fix you can add a separate css for IE8 and add a fix only for IE8.

Use the following to add your css specific to IE8.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    /* css for IE 8 */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: IF someone chooses to filter out IE8 a better approach is this: <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8"><![endif]--> . That sets the html class to ie8 and you can use CSS as .ie8 .yourSpecialDiv { //css };

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the HTML code.